Can I compare two C++ compiled libraries to see what code was changed?
I have a C++ repository, and during a "throw everything including the kitchen sink" moment to fix an issue, I came up with a fix, however I don't know the exact code I used to fix it, and subsequently changed code that I can't recover.
I have the compiled DLL library that works, but my source code no longer matches the library (don't ask).
Is there a way to compare my compiled DLL that works, against the code base, or a file compiled by the code base, to see what I did to make it work?
Hope that makes sense.

Brutally hard. If you optimized the code then the output of a decompiler will look about a much like the source as a banana does after a trip through the blender.

Source control solves this very problem.

I have source control, but when you are up at 2am solving an issue, sometimes you change something and it works and you didn't commit. So.. yea :(

How good are you at reading assembly?

"Is there a way to ... see what I did to make it work?" - short answer, not a straight forward way, no.  A lot of reverse-engineering effort would be needed.  C++ is compiled not interpreted, so it is simply not designed to recover the original source code the way you are asking for. You may just have to bite the bullet and revert back to your known codebase and then reimplement the fix again, hopefully it is still in your mind somewhere. And then check it in to your source control this time. Always check in, even late at night. It only takes a few seconds.

In fact, I would suggest reverting back to your known code base and working through to find a fix again - but take a breath and do it more systematically this time.   After a "kitchen sink" approach, there is often some other new problem introduced which will bite hard in future - and probably need reversion anyway.  You will probably have something in the back of your mind that will help go a bit faster (or avoid going down some dead-end paths).  The goal should be to get a fix that you can explain, as well as passing test cases.


Is there a way to compare my compiled DLL that works, against the code base

No.
There is no way to transform a compiled DLL into something that could be compared against a code base.
The best you can do is compile your current code and compare the two DLLs.  This would mean that you are comparing machine code, or with the right viewer, assembly code.
